# How to convert 0 byte array to string in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsstring

In Java, we can create a 0-byte array like

```
byte[] arr = new byte[];
```

What is the syntax to create a 0-byte array in Objective-C?

Also, how do I create a 1-byte array in Objective-C?

And after creating, how do I convert it to an `NSString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create and free 0 length array:

```
char *arr = malloc(0);
// do something with arr, actually you cant do much with it
free(arr);
```

to convert null-terminated c string to `NSString`:

```
const char *cstr = "test";
NSString *str = @(cstr);
// or
NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cstr];
```

to convert char array to `NSString`:

```
char arr[5] = "test";
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:arr length:5 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

you can check [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) doc for more details

Comment: I want a 1 byte array..I wrote like this   char arr[1] = "";
 NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:arr length:1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);But here str is coming nil..Actually For mqtt connection I have to send 0 byte array while setting will msg like [mosquittoClient setWill:string1  toTopic:myTopic withQos:2 retain:YES]; where string1 is 0-byte array and after that i have to publish 1-byte message like [mosquittoClient publishString:string2 toTopic:mytopic withQos:2 retain:YES]; where string2 is 1 byte array..Please give some idea..

Comment: @user2552518 I am confused, your method accept `char *` or `NSString`? If you want to create 0-length `NSString`, just use `@""`. If you want 1 character string, just use `@"a"` or whatever.